# how to flatten the nested array in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am using forkJoin to subscribe multiple inner observable. How can I flat nested array to single level array.

```
const x$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const y$ = of([2, 4]);

x$.pipe(
  switchMap((t) => {
    const innerArr$ = t.map((z) => y$.pipe(map((_) => _.map((y) => y * z))));
    return forkJoin(innerArr$);
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Playground Link: [Rxjs stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u9hjmw?devtoolsheight=60)

Expected Output:

```
[2,4,4,8,6,12,8,16]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to the answer by @Picci if you want a stream of numbers.

If you want to wind up with a single array instead, you can flatten the result in the subscription:

```
x$.pipe(
  switchMap((t) => {
    const innerArr$ = t.map((z) => y$.pipe(map((_) => _.map((y) => y * z))));
    return forkJoin(innerArr$);
  })
)
.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log([].concat.apply([], res));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
x$.pipe(
  switchMap((t) => {
    const innerArr$ = t.map((z) => y$.pipe(map((_) => _.map((y) => y * z))));
    return forkJoin(innerArr$);
  }),
  mergeMap((aa) => from(aa).pipe(mergeMap((a) => a)))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The key here is

- `mergeMap` is actually a flatten Observable-like objects (actually
  `mergeMap` was formerly known as `flatMap`)
- an Array is treated as an Observable since it actually can represent a stream of data, which is what an Observable is